# SQL return all the values if Boolean is null

Tags: sql, hibernate, boolean

This may be a silly question, but I'm stuck in this issue. I have a method in hibernate like the following

```
public List<User> searchUser(String name, Boolean booleanCheck) {
    Query hqlQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User user where user.booleanCheck = :booleanCheck");
    return hqlQuery.setParameter("booleanCheck", booleanCheck).list();
}
```

What I need is if the booleanCheck parameter is null, it should return all the values. If I have a true or false value, it should return the selected values.

At the moment it returns no values if it's null. Is there something I could do to get the desirable output?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the usual way to shortcut a parameter in SQL:

```
Query hqlQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User user where (:booleanCheck is NULL or user.booleanCheck = :booleanCheck)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must differ your queries, when value is null. In your implementation the generated query is

```
select * from User user where user.booleanCheck = null;
```

which will indeed find nothing. When booleanCheck is null, you must generate the query

```
select * from User user where user.booleanCheck is null;
```